# change my old Google API python user account provisioning script to use the new API

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

The script below is used to add new users to our google mail.  It is called from the bash add-user script and creates user accounts for everything a new user will need including UNIX and Samba accounts.  I need help understanding what has to change to  work with the new API. This is run from a Solaris10 system and will soon migrate to a RHEL/Centos6 server.  There are similar scripts that are used to change a users password on all accounts and to disable accounts. I gather that I will need to  put something into JSON format  but it is not clear to me how that works.

Thanks for your help.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import getpass
import gdata.apps.service

if len(sys.argv) < 7:
    print 'usage:\n ', sys.argv[0], ' username lastname firstname \
    nickname password user \n '
    exit
else:
    domain = 'channing.harvard.edu'
    user = sys.argv[6]
    pw = ''

    print '\nEnter your Google Apps login password.'
    while True:
        try:
            while not pw:
                pw = getpass.getpass()
            if not pw:
                    print 'Password cannot be blank.'

            email = user + '@' + domain                   
            service = gdata.apps.service.AppsService(email=email, \
    domain=domain, password=pw)
            service.ProgrammaticLogin()
        except gdata.service.BadAuthentication, e:
            print e
            print 'Please enter the correct password for ' + user
            pw = ''
        except:
            pw=''
        else: break

    username = sys.argv[1]
    lastname = sys.argv[2]
    firstname = sys.argv[3]
    nickname = sys.argv[4]
    newpassword = sys.argv[5]
    print '\nCreating new Google Apps account for', firstname, \
    lastname, 'with username', username, 'and password', \
    newpassword, '\n' ;
    try:
        service.CreateUser(username, lastname, firstname, \
   newpassword)
    except gdata.apps.service.AppsForYourDomainException , e:
        print e.reason# or process the exception in some other way
        print 'unable to create account for ' + username
        print username + ' already exists'
        exit()
    service.CreateNickname(username, nickname)
```

I hope this code is clear.  I had to mangle it a bit with '\' to get it to fit.